# Problems with md5sum and the script

Tags: python, bash

**my problem is**: i can't generate and store my md5sum of my directory in my script

this is my scrip

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
md5= `md5sum /etc/shadow`
```

what happen is simple the "md5sum /etc/shadow" is stored on my variable md5 and do not generate de firm

someone can tell me what  i'm doing wrong

Comment: That's not the way to run bash commands in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run Bash script as you would do it in Perl, you need to use [the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), which will run the command and return you the output of the program. You need to get this output, by [using `communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("md5sum /etc/shadow", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
md5 = p.communicate()[0]
print md5
```

For the record, the backtick notation is an alias to `repr`, but it is deprecated and removed in Python 3. It has nothing to do with bash commands:

```
>>> `id`
'<built-in function id>'
>>> repr(id)
'<built-in function id>'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already provided (using subprocess), you can also calculate the md5 sum yourself:

```
> md5sum sean.bin
167f3284b5de3bc7dfafaa98b068a65e  sean.bin

>>> import hashlib
>>> md5 = hashlib.md5()
>>> md5.update(open("sean.bin").read())
>>> md5.hexdigest()
'167f3284b5de3bc7dfafaa98b068a65e'
```

And here is how I would do it with subprocess:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = "md5sum sean.bin"
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> out, err = proc.communicate()
>>> out.split(" ")[0]
'167f3284b5de3bc7dfafaa98b068a65e'
```